# How Should I Share Thunderbird-Lightning-Tasks Between Workstations?

Tags: thunderbird, network-shares, file-sharing, multiple-users, lightning

I originally submitted this [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/how_should_i_share_lightning_tasks_between_workstations?rfm=1), but I don't expect a reply.

After migrating a company from MS Exchange server to Google Apps, I had a hard time finding a comparable replacement for Outlook's "Tasks" feature.

I eventually came across Lightning and it is the closest match I've found. Yet, I'm struggling to devise a way for multiple workstations to see the same task set in Lightning.

Currently, I'm having the key-employee (the one entering and managing the tasks) export tasks to a network-share-folder a couple of times a day. And then, any employee who wants to sync with her lightning tasks, must delete all tasks they previously imported, and then do an import of what she exported to that network-share-folder (mentioned earlier).

I'm looking for a way to automate this, so that each non-task-managing-employee can always view (in Lightning) the latest tasks created by the task-managing-employee.

I wish there was a "Sync with Master" button or somthing like that.

Can you suggested some method by which I might acheived this objective of "almost realtime sharing of tasks between mutliple lightning clients"?

These workstations are Windows, but right now I'm playing around with Thunderbird-Lightning using Ubuntu. I came aross a location where tasks are stored:
/home/username/.thunderbird/smmek7fl.default/calendar-data/local.sqlite

I made a copy of this file on my desktop, then I deleted all tasks (from within lightning). After this, I copied over this file with the copy I made before deleting the tasks, and restarted Thunderbird. The tasks were back.

There is probably a "local.sqlite" file on Windows too. Perhaps I can schedule batch scripts to routinely copy this file from the task-mananging-employee's computer to the network-share-folder. And then, on each non-task-managing-employee's computer, schedule batch scripts to routinely overwrite their copy of local.sqlite with the one from the share?

What do you think of this idea? Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you symlink that folder to a folder on the network? Then, all installations of Thunderbird would in effect be looking to the same folder for tasks.

Comment: You should be warned that the developers of Thunderbird have all but said that it is a very low priority. Furthermore you should be aware that Thunderbird itself has been basically discontinued. So any bugs you might discovered are unlikeyl to be fixed.

Comment: Guess not: http://dottech.org/tech-news/73932/bye-bye-thunderbird/

Comment: Yet, despite this, version 15 was just released.

Comment: @LonnieBest - I actually made a mistake in my original comment. Lighting has been discontinued. Feel free to delete your comment about Microsoft paying me because you can confirm my statements about Lighting yourself.  Feel free to look at the changes to Thunderbird there have been articles to support my views on the program itself.